# header files in C and its usage

Tags: c, header-files

The library header files contain only the declarations of functions. So, how exactly does the function run when we call the library functions?

Ex: `int strcmp ( const char * str1, const char * str2 );` is the declaration for strcmp function in C.

When we call strcmp function in a program, how exactly does the strcmp function get executed if the function body is not present in the header files?

Comment: Programs need to be compiled and *linked* in order to run.  The code for the library routines is in a library somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code that you want to use like `printf` is already compiled and stored somewhere. Your final executable is built when the linker links your object code with the standard library.

try `gcc -c somefile.c` and see what you get.

Also try `gcc -v` option and learn the output that it gives.

Find out what `ld` command does and you shall get your answer.

Also this what I think should help you : [All about compilation/linking/related](http://www.tenouk.com/Bufferoverflowc/Bufferoverflow1c.html)

**UPDATE :**

Also Imagine if you defined `printf` for every program in `stdio.h` and you included `stdio.h`

***program.c*** :

```
#include <stdio.h>  //suppose this contains definition of printf     

int main()
{            

/*Call printf()  somewhere or maybe not */

}
```

gcc program.c -o output

So here all your definitions that are there in `stdio.h` would be replaced in the `program.c` file and your executable `output` will become pretty **HUGE**. Instead It would be a better idea to call functions that you use frequently like `printf` in `stdio.h` from one place whenever they are needed

Answer (score 3):

header files only contain function declarations. That is one of their main purposes, to expose the content you have to work with without worrying about the implementation

As far as the location of the implementation, a runtime library is added in to your program upon building, so as a coder, you can call all of these functions since you have a "forward" declaration of their function definitions, but it is not until runtime when the implementation is loaded.

The reason for this is because it would be silly to copy the implementation code of something like, say, printf in every single program that uses it. This would be quite a waste of memory! So instead, only the declarations are exposed to you, the programmer, and the OS shares the implementation of the function in memory at runtime.

Comment: Woops! thanks! though you could put more in a header if u wanted to.

Comment: http://www.umich.edu/~eecs381/handouts/CHeaderFileGuidelines.pdf Found a good read for both of us :D

Answer (score 3):

To understand how strcmp can be used by the program even tough the compiler only sees its declaration one has to understand the process of linking. Compiling a C program consists of three steps:

1. Preprocessing (dump all included headers into the source code)
2. Compilation (make an object file from the source code)
3. Linking (link multiple object files together)

In the third step, the so called *linker* (usually `ld`) basically dumps the content of all linked object files into an executable file and resolves all symbols. A symbol is anything that has a global name such as a function or a global variable.

When your program calls `strcmp` the object file generated by your compiler does not actually contain the definition of said function. Rather there is just a reference to the symbol `strcmp` that is going to be resolved later by the linker. The linker examines all object files and also global libraries and then resolves these references.

Answer (score 2):

`strcmp` is in the runtime library, which gets added to your program when you build an executable. The details of how this works vary between operating systems.

Answer (score 2):

It's no different to any other user-defined header in this case.

If you don't include the corresponding header (e.g. `string.h` for `strcmp`) then an implicit declaration is done by the compiler.

If the function definition is not found (i.e. missing in the library as per your assumption) at runtime then linker is going to complain when linking with the standard C library which is done by default ( For example at the time of doing `-lc` in case of gcc).

Comment: The question does not ask about missing declarations or the purpose of declarations, so the first two paragraphs in this answer are irrelevant. The third paragraph says something about a function definition being not found, but the question also does not ask about not finding a function. It asks the converse, how **is** a function found. This “answer” does not answer the question about how `strcmp` can be executed when its definition apparently does not appear in the program. Although it (finally) mentions the C library, it does not explain linking object modules.

Comment: @EricPostpischil `When we call strcmp function in a program, how exactly does the strcmp function get executed if the function body is not present in the header files` Though function bodies don't usually present in the headers, the question is clear: *What if the function definition is missing* Or that's how I understand it.

Comment: No, the question is essentially ”How is it that the function definition is **not** missing even though it is not in the header?” If the question were as you suggest, then the questioner would be reporting linker error messages and asking why they get those errors. They are not asking about an unexpectedly missing definition. They are asking about an unexpectedly present definition.

Comment: That's what I said. Linker would complain if it couldn't find. There's no code given but an example case of strcmp. Your suggestion that *how the function definition is found if they don't present in the header* seems a valid argument, I can't make up that's what OP really asked.

Answer (score 1):

It is present in the compiled library. When you compile your project while linking to some library, the pre-compiled library gets added to the final compilation.